# Check two arrays for a JSON property within them

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, d3.js, filter

**Intro:**
I'm using the `d3.js` library to draw a force-layout-graph. To make the update process of the graph look smoth I want to check an array called `nodes`, that holds all the current `nodes` in the graph and the new `incoming json object` if they have a shared element based on the `name` property each `node` has.
**Sample JSON:**

```
{
    "nodes":[
        {"name":"Harry Potter", "shortname":"Harry", "id":0},
        {"name":"Severus Snape", "shortname":"Severus", "id":1}
     ],
     "links":[
        {"source":0,"target":1,"relation":"hasTeacher"}
     ]
}
```

Each `name` is unique (*yes, I know some of you will argue about the reason why the name shouldn't be unique*), this `object` will be an input parameter for a function. 
**The function:**
Following function will push all the new nodes to the graph.

```
function pushNewElements(json) {
    var len = json.nodes.length;
    var difference = json.nodes.filter(function (el) {
        return isInGraph(el, len);
    });
    difference.forEach(function (node) {
        nodes.push(node);
    });
}
```

**The `filter()` function**
This function should work like a filter and get the difference between the `nodes` and `json.nodes` array. After many tests, this is the best that I could come up with.

```
function isInGraph(jnode, arrayLength) {
//runs vor each entry in json.nodes, 1 of these objects is jnode
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length + arrayLength; i++) {
    //nodes.length will return 0 at the beginning, 
    //since no object is in the graph yet, the function won't run enough time.
        try {
            //We have to try this, because nodes[i] might be out of bound
            if (jnode.name == nodes[i].name) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            java.alert(err.message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

`java.alert()` is a custom function that prints on the java console.
**Known issues:**

- `nodes` will initially be empty. So I can't iterate over it like I would normally do. Filter should return everything.
- `nodes` and `json.nodes` could contain the same data, thus filter should return nothing.
- `json.nodes` has all data of `nodes` + some extra data. For the same data should return true, for the new data false.
- `json.nodes` has less data than `nodes`, filter should return all missing nodes.
- `nodes` and `json.nodes` have a compleatly different data set, all should return false.

**What am I asking?**
I know that this is a big task. I'm not asking anyone here to solve it. I just want to know:

- Is there a better option than using `filter()`?
- Do I make an obvious mistake in my `isInGraph()`?
- Is there a good pattern to iterate over 2 arrays in JavaScript at the same time?

Thanks to anyone who has read so far. If you feel like I could improve this question since it might be not so well written or you (partly) know how to solve this problem, let me please know.

Comment: *"this JSON object will be an input parameter for a function"* The function as you've shown it doesn't accept JSON. It accepts an object. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and you're not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: I'm using `var json = JSON.parse(stringObj);
    pushNewElements(json);`, correct me if I'm wrong: But wouldn't that make `json` a `JSON Object`?

Comment: No. Once it's parsed, it's just an object, like any other object. JSON is a *textual notation*.

Comment: Ok, I'll change it, thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only made few mistakes, the general idea is ok, I corrected/commented the code:

```
var input = {
    "nodes": [
        { "name": "Harry Potter", "shortname": "Harry", "id": 0 },
        { "name": "Severus Snape", "shortname": "Severus", "id": 1 }
    ],
    "links": [
        { "source": 0, "target": 1, "relation": "hasTeacher" }
    ]
};

var nodes = [
    // { "name": "Harry Potter", "shortname": "Harry", "id": 0 },
    { "name": "Severus Snape", "shortname": "Severus", "id": 1 }
];

function pushNewElements(json) {
    // you don't need this
    // var len = json.nodes.length;

    var difference = json.nodes.filter(function (el) {
        return !isInGraph(el); // << you want the nodes that are NOT in nodes
    });

    difference.forEach(function (node) {
        nodes.push(node);
    });
}

function isInGraph(jnode) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        // if the names match, return true now
        if (jnode.name == nodes[i].name) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // no match found (works with nodes.length == 0)
    return false;
}

pushNewElements(input);
console.log(nodes);
```

This code works for the three obvious case (`nodes` with 0, 1 or 2 of the elements). Now here comes the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) one-liner:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var input = {
    "nodes": [
        { "name": "Harry Potter", "shortname": "Harry", "id": 0 },
        { "name": "Severus Snape", "shortname": "Severus", "id": 1 }
    ],
    "links": [
        { "source": 0, "target": 1, "relation": "hasTeacher" }
    ]
};

var nodes = [
    // { "name": "Harry Potter", "shortname": "Harry", "id": 0 },
    { "name": "Severus Snape", "shortname": "Severus", "id": 1 }
];

// unionBy returns unique values from two arrays, elements are compared by 'name'
nodes = _.unionBy(nodes, json.nodes, 'name');

console.log(nodes);
/* output:
[
    { "name": "Severus Snape", "shortname": "Severus", "id": 1 },
    { "name": "Harry Potter", "shortname": "Harry", "id": 0 }
]
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for the input so far. So I have to use the `lodash` library? What exactly does it do in this context?

Comment: You don't have to but with lodash, you don't need two functions, what you want to do is done in one line of code. In the second piece of code, new elements are added to `nodes` (I added a console.log for clarity).